# Groovy/Grails - Error at run-app with Enums

Tags: grails, groovy, enums, run-app

I'm facing this error

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching
>   constructor for: AnimalInfoType(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer,
>   java.lang.Integer) when

starting the app via "run-app" and I've created the constructor for Enum, as seen below:

```
    package jogoanimais

    public enum AnimalInfoType
    {
      ANIMAL(1), 
      ACTION(2)

        final int value
        private AnimalInfoType(int value) {
          this.value = value
        }

        int value() { value }    
    }
```

My domain class is like that:

```
    class AnimaisTreeMap {

       String nodeDescription
       AnimalInfoType nodeInfo
       AnimaisTreeMap yesAnswerNode
       AnimaisTreeMap noAnswerNode

        static constraints = {
            yesAnswerNode nullable:true
            noAnswerNode nullable:true        

        }
        static mappedBy = [ yesAnswerNode: "none", noAnswerNode: "none" ]   
        static mapping = {
            yesAnswerNode cascade: 'delete'
            noAnswerNode cascade: 'delete'
        }
    }
```

And at my BootStrap.groovy I fill the table like that:

```
    def noAnswer =  new AnimaisTreeMap(nodeDescription:"macaco", 
                                       nodeInfo: AnimalInfoType.ANIMAL,
                                       noAnswerNode:null, 
                                       yesAnswerNode:null)
    noAnswer.save(failOnError: true)
    def yesAnswer =  new AnimaisTreeMap(nodeDescription:"tubarão", 
                                        nodeInfo: AnimalInfoType.ANIMAL,
                                        noAnswerNode:null, 
                                        yesAnswerNode:null)
    yesAnswer.save(failOnError: true)           

    new AnimaisTreeMap(nodeDescription:"vive na água", 
                       nodeInfo: AnimalInfoType.ACTION,
                       noAnswerNode: noAnswer, 
                       yesAnswerNode:  yesAnswer).
                       save(failOnError: true)                  
}
```

What am I doing wrong at BootStrap.groovy?

Comment: That constructor isn't `String, Integer, Integer`

Comment: @tim_yates yeah...and it made me lose too much time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the enum constructor and its public definition. It's not necessary, all classes are public by default.

And edit the class ended by Enum. AnimalInfoTypeEnum.

```
enum AnimalInfoTypeEnum
{
  ANIMAL(1), 
  ACTION(2)

    final int value

    int value() { value }    
}
```

Comment: I've changed as you said, the table was sucessfully created with records at "run-app" phase but when I render the app it raises:

  *org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Cannot add Domain class [class jogoanimais.AnimalInfoType]. It is not a Domain!*

Comment: Rename the class enum as I said in the answer

Comment: In fact, I didn't realize that the classe should have "Enum" at its name.

I've got success with this code

    enum AnimalInfoTypeEnum
    {
        
        ANIMAL(1),
        ACTION(2)

        final int value
        AnimalInfoTypeEnum(int value) {
          this.value = value
        }
        int value() { value } 
    }

Comment: yeap, thanks for all. It was a detail, but it took too much time from me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
package jogoanimais

enum AnimalInfoType{
   ANIMAL(1), 
   ACTION(2)

   private final int value

   private AnimalInfoType(int value) {
      this.value = value
   }

   int value() { value }
}
```

Wouldn't let me comment, don't have enough rep.

Comment: How is that different to the question?

Comment: @tim_yates the difference is the "private" modifier to variable "value"

Comment: Ah... Not sure that will have any effect... But I guess Andre will know ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates like I said, I can't add comments to questions because I'm under 50 rep, otherwise it would've been a comment. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050451/how-to-use-enum-in-grails-not-in-domain-class

Comment: @DrakePHP I tried it, but no success at all. I forgot to put mu BootStrap.groovy and I think I'm referring my Enum wrong in there